# Как сделать дополнительные аргументы функции в JS

Tags: javascript

Как сделать вот так (не знаю как это описать, это как дополнительный аргумент-объект):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я попробовал что-то такое, но по-моему это какие-то костыли (+ сверху не вылезает "?options"):

```js
var f = (x, y) => {
    if(typeof x == "object") {
        console.log("options:", x)
    } else {
        console.log("x, y:", x, y)
    }
};
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В JS нет перегрузки функций. Так что в данном случае это не костыль, а весьма рабочий и часто используемый подход.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте в качестве аргумента `...options`.

```js
let testFunction = (...options) => {
  return `options:${options}`
}

console.info(testFunction(1, 2, 3, "test", true))
```